# Why does my browser show different IP and ASN (Autonomous System Number) number for streaming service(Youtube/Netflix)?

Tags: networking, ip, cdn

What I tried! (Next follows my question)
I wanted IP range for streaming services. After researching, I came across getting the ASN number for particular service like youtube.com/netflix.com.

Fetching IP Ranges from ASN number was easy. Netflix has ASN as `AS2906`. Querying services like ipinfo.io gives me IP Ranges `https://ipinfo.io/AS2906#block-ranges`

But when I tried visiting `netflix.com` from browser, it gives me different IP Address and ASN Number. (reference : Screenshot of browser along with IP address plugin. On the right side I see Server IP address not in range of what I got from ipinfo.io and also the ASN Number belongs to Amazon and not of netflix i.e `AS2906`).

[image]

Question ?

Why is the IP Address different from the IP Ranges that I collected ?
Also why is ASN Number not matching?
How do I concretely find all the IP Ranges for streaming services ?

Comment: To the Person negating the answer : I would greatly appreciate if you could comment and/or improvise the question or at-least give a hint on what is lacking in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the IP Address different from the IP Ranges that I collected ? Also why is ASN Number not matching?

Because organizations are not required to host *everything* on their AS.

AS numbers are issued to organizations – AS2906 belongs to Netflix the company, it never was issued to "netflix.com" in the first place. Now the company might have an AS number for some purposes, but can still use regular ISP services and cloud services for other purposes.

The other address you found isn't just Amazon in general, it's part of *Amazon AWS* – a hosting company (aka "cloud service provider") that Netflix and thousands of other companies use to host their websites; the address belongs to a server rented through AWS's "EC2" service.

So Netflix uses AS2906 to run their specialized "Streaming Services" CDN, but at the same time they rely on a generic hosting company (Amazon's AWS) to serve generic things like their public-facing website (i.e. things that AWS EC2 is good at but a video-streaming CDN would be bad at).

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question. :) 
I got the point what you are saying. 
Now suppose, if I want to block all netflix.com streaming services IP, then what should I do ? Is it ok to get the netflix.com ASN and get all IP Ranges ? If I do so, will it block netflix.com or will it still be accessible as the IP we saw in above case is different? Please bear with my limited knowledge of ASNs. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In short, Netflix is hosting their streaming services behind AWS. Therefore, you will be getting AWS's AS name and number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Got it. 
So if I want to block/whitelist netflix's streaming, then how should I get all of it's IP addresses ?

Comment: It is hard because IP might changes from time to time due to data center allocation. It is easier to block all connections if it is resolved to *.netflix.com.